# some documentation about _onchange_spec() methose in odoo

Tags: odoo

in chapter 6 of the book Odoo Development Cookbook the author introduces the _onchange_spec () methode  and he presented it as a follow :
This method will retrieve the updates that are triggered by the odification of which other field. It does this by examining the form view of the model (remember, onchange methods are normally called by the web client).
i need more details

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the stackoverflow community.

**The main objective** of the _onchange_spec () method is to call the onchange method from the server side.

**In the example of the book you mention, it is explained that:**

> you can do the required computation yourself, but this is not always
>   possible as the onchange method can be added or modified by a
>   third-party addon module installed on the instance that you don 't
>   know about.

**When called:**
Passing no argument. This method will retrieve the updates that are triggered by the modification of which other field. It does this by examining the form view of the model.

**How to Use it:**
You must use it when you want to manually run an onchange method and compute something before creating the registry or updating it.

**Example**

```
@api.multi
def return_all_books(self):
    self.ensure_one
    wizard = self.env['library.returns.wizard']
    #this is the manual change (update the member)
    values = {'member_id': self.id}
    #this examines the form to find the changes
    specs = wizard._onchange_spec()
    #This gets the values of the onchange
    updates = wizard.onchange(values, ['member_id'], specs)
    #Combine the results with the new manually added value
    values.update(updates.get('value', {}))
    record = wizard.create(values)
```

For another implementation you can check below.

[you can see a implementation for testing here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8f4b98e67fe49516c0c830524de351db67c58357/odoo/addons/test_new_api/tests/test_onchange.py)